# How to know SQL Server connection string?

Tags: vb6, sql-server-2000, connection-string, runtime-error, decode

**Hello,**

I have a VB6 program which I only have the compiled executable file and not the source code. This program connects to a SQL Server 2000 database. I get the,

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no
>   default driver specified

error. Is there a way to know what is the connection string coded inside the VB6 program? VB6 De-compilers did not work.

Comment: Have you tried VB-Decompiler. Its nice tool. I had too similar situation, and I got success with few headbangs.

Comment: Thanks but tried it and it did not show the connection string code.

Comment: If the app is compiled you should still be able to see the hard coded strings within.  I would suggest just sitting with a hex debugger and going through it.  [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) should do the trick.  I've been there before and this is MONOTONOUS!  Good luck!  ;o)

Comment: If it is using ODBC can you turn on logging for ODBC?

Comment: I did not have time to go through the suggestions. But I will get back. Thanks.

Comment: Is this on the computer it was originally compiled on? Do you have access to any computer that the code has successfully run on before?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a weird try, might be a help that is using Cheat Engine, generally used for cheatings Facebook games. This is a nice tool that helps you reading the changing values in the memory. 
What we do is :
We execute the game in FF or Chrome. Open CheatEngine and from there we select the FF or Chrome from its proces windows. Now in its home screen, you can have search option in the memory registers. What we generally do is  we search for a value on screen that changes on every step. So we place the value and set the search type as exact search and clicks on new search. In the left list box , it will give you 10000's of memory addresses, but dont worry. In your next turn, check the value after chnage, now put that value and click on next scan. Now you will have lesser address, repeat it until you exactly two register, generally comes in 3-4 clicks and 4-5 retries , so it will take around 15-20 mins of your time.

I am not sure that this will work. In your case, you have to find a  unique keyword like `ODBC Driver Manager` , why because this register or its nearby register might contain the value.

If it seems a hectic and failure process, still you can explore the CheatEngine as it is full of options and nice small small utilities. Check that out, it might be a help. Or send me its exe, i will give a try for you, if you wish.

**I know this is not an appropriate answer , but this might be a help , as he is totally stucked, kindly do not downvote. As its solely his decision whether to try or not**